# how to identify a gui class in java

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

i am working on a project in java (using eclipse) that was developed by other programmers with whom i have no contact. how can i identify which classes are for the gui? there are files that import java.awt but i didn't find any mention of swt.

every time i think i found a gui class, i try to view it with the windowbuilder editor in design mode but get the error message:

This is not a GUI class and can't be edited graphically
The parser parsed the compilation unit, but can't identify any GUI toolkit.

can anyone explain this to me? i am new user with eclipse and java.

Comment: Those most likely use the `GroupLayout` and use that as a way of identifying that. They tend to also have an `init()` method and extend `JFrame`. If you want to see what the GUI looks like: run it.

Comment: Look for imports such as `import javax.swing.*;`  Also, if the class `extends JFrame`

Comment: @user2542027 or `JPanel` or `JDialog`

Comment: Or in other words: are you sure it is a SWT application and not a Swing application?

Answer (score 1):

There are not a lot of popular Java GUI frameworks available. Use *Eclipse Search -> File -> Containing text* for substrings

```
   javax.swing
   java.awt
   org.eclipse.swt
```

Each attempt will list the candidate classes for one of the three major known frameworks. A few other non relevant classes may be listed but they will not be common and you will quickly find which technologies are used. The application may also mix multiple frameworks (for instance, swing+awt).

These search substrings are unlikely to occur in java code just by chance; even if they would, this is easy to recognize.

Comment: a search turned up nothing for swt but swing and awt were present. while looking at Preferences got the following error while trying to view Swing (submenu in WindowBuilder): Unable to create the selected preference page.
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.ToolkitProvider

Answer (score 0):

these tow packages have GUI classes

```
java.awt.*
javax.swing.*
```

Comment: probably not swt; just has awt and swing in code but i suspect there something is missing from the eclipse install (plugin perhaps)

Comment: SWT is not part of standard java but provided by eclipse. You can search your project of the package "org.eclipse.swt." and you will know which java files are related to swt and weather it's being used or not. also when you create GUI using java, sometimes you can't see it visually in IDE because of some not supported functionality in from IDE. Because some developer don't use Visual editor to desing the GUI. So it could also be the case, if it's the case, you will be getting errors/exceptions in that case. But if you compile and run, you will be able to see the output.

Comment: i didn't find org.eclipse.swt in the code. just awt and swing. you may be right that previous developers did not use a visual editor; unfortunately, i have no way of knowing. the program runs ok; i can see menus, windows and dialog boxes at runtime. in order to make changes in position of gui elements, it would be nice to view it visually in the ide. i'm a visual studio developer so perhaps i am bit spoiled ;-).

Comment: no man, sorry, all you can do is to debug the code, know the architecture of the application and start by one use case to another. Once you understand it, you will be able to make quick changes but you will always have to compile and run the program to see the changes.

Comment: at least i won't be wasting my time looking for a simpler solution. i appreciate the good advice from everyone on where to look in the code.